# How to add an eventListener to get event data from JWPlayer

Tags: javascript, listener, dom-events, jwplayer

I don't understanding what code is needed to simply output any interaction with the Flash JW Player. Below is a code demo from their [documentation](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/FlashEvents) (results in addControllerListener being undefined). Some more details in the [JW Player Flash API](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/FlashApi).

```
function muteTracker(obj) { alert('the new mute state is: '+obj.state); };
player.addControllerListener("MUTE","muteTracker");
```

I want to extend this to include functions to track all other interactions such as play, seek, fullscreen etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track! If you check out [the player API](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player4Api#Settinglisteners), you'll notice that there are three methods for adding listeners:

- player.addControllerListener(EVENT,myFunction);
- player.addModelListener(EVENT,myFunction);
- player.addViewListener(EVENT,myFunction);

Pair that with the events list (http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player4Events) and you're good to go. Thus, if you're looking to listen for seek events, it would look something like:

```
player.addViewListener(ViewEvent.PLAY,myFunction);
```

or for seek,

```
player.addViewListener(ViewEvent.SEEK,myFunction);
```

Best,

Zach

Developer, LongTail Video